# javascript replace with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that contains a lot of

```
<span style="font-size:8px;">...</span> 
<span style="font-size:14px;"> ...</span>
```

And i want to replace all font-size values to given value. So i need a regexp to replace all chars beetween "font-size:" and "px;"

P.s. i use Rangy JS library

```
var iframe = $('iframe')[0];
            var sel =  rangy.getIframeSelection(iframe);
            selected_html=sel.toHtml();
            selected_html.replace("font-size:<some regexp>px;", "36");
```

Can you suggest a proper regexp?

Comment: Where is the string coming from? I suggest you get rid of the inline styles, add a class and do it in css.

Comment: Don't use regex for html. You're using rangy already, why not modify the attributes on the nice DOM nodes it returns instead of regexing html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.replace(/(font-size:)\d+(px;)/g, "$1"+36+"$2");
```

Comment: nice but you should add some explanation!

Comment: $1 == (font-size:) && $2 == (px;) nice Answer.

Comment: Better allow some spaces.  To keep the spaces use: `.replace(/(font-size:\s*)\d+(\s*px;)/g, "$1"+36+"$2");` Otherwise: `.replace(/(font-size:)\s*\d+\s*(px;)/g, "$1"+36+"$2");`